# Display output in one line SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this sql statement

```
SELECT STYLERELEASE.StyleID,SUM(STYLERELEASE.Quantity) as [Total rel],
       SUM(STYLERECEIVE.Quantity) as [Total Receive],
       STYLERELEASE.Quantity - STYLERECEIVE.Quantity AS [Balance],
       ToWhom 
FROM STYLERELEASE 
       JOIN STYLERECEIVE 
          ON STYLERELEASE.ReleaseID  = STYLERECEIVE.ReleaseID 
             AND STYLERELEASE.ToWhom = STYLERECEIVE.FromWhere 
WHERE STYLERELEASE.StyleID = 'SN00000' 
  AND ToWhom = 'Repair' 
  OR ToWhom = 'Client' 
GROUP BY STYLERELEASE.StyleID, STYLERELEASE.Quantity, STYLERECEIVE.Quantity, STYLERELEASE.ToWhom
```

which gives this output

```
+-------+---------+-------------+-------+------+
|StyleID|Total rel|Total Receive|Balance|Towhom|
+-------+---------+-------------+-------+------+
|SN00000|30       |55           |-25    |Client|
+-------+---------+-------------+-------+------+
|SN00000|100      |55           |45     |Repair|
+-------+---------+-------------+-------+------+
```

i want my output to become like this

```
+-------+---------+-------------+-------+------+---------+-------------+-------+------+
|StyleID|Total rel|Total Receive|Balance|Towhom|Total rel|Total Receive|Balance|Towhom|
+-------+---------+-------------+-------+------+---------+-------------+-------+------+
|SN00000|30       |55           |-25    |Client|100      |55           |45     |Repair|
+-------+---------+-------------+-------+------+---------+-------------+-------+------+
```

how can i achieve this any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Toni Almeida thanks but i need the 2 output with the same style id to be displayed in a single line any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi @Vince, I've just edited your question to better legibility, if something is wrong with my edit please revert the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

presuming the current query returns one `styleid` for 'client' and 'repair'

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT STYLERELEASE.StyleID,
           SUM(STYLERELEASE.Quantity) as [Total rel],
           SUM(STYLERECEIVE.Quantity) as [Total Receive],
           STYLERELEASE.Quantity - STYLERECEIVE.Quantity AS [Balance], 
           ToWhom 
    FROM STYLERELEASE 
    JOIN STYLERECEIVE 
      ON STYLERELEASE.ReleaseID  = STYLERECEIVE.ReleaseID 
     AND STYLERELEASE.ToWhom = STYLERECEIVE.FromWhere 
    WHERE STYLERELEASE.StyleID = 'SN00000' 
      AND ToWhom = 'Repair' 
       OR ToWhom = 'Client' 
    GROUP BY STYLERELEASE.StyleID, STYLERELEASE.Quantity, STYLERECEIVE.Quantity, STYLERELEASE
)

SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT * FROM cte WHERE ToWhom='Client' ) client
JOIN ( SELECT * FROM cte WHERE ToWhom='Repair' ) repair
  ON client.STYLEID = repair.STYLEID
```

Comment: @ T I thanks fot the answer it worked but i StyleID is repeated how can i remove it? 
like this

SN00000 |  30      |       55      |    -25  | Client |    100    |      55       |   45    |  Repair

Comment: @Vince you can and should specify the columns you want within the select. i was just being lazy...

Comment: @Vince if this answers your requirment please consider to accept it.

Comment: @ T I can you specify in which select statement ?

Comment: @ T I many thanks for the answer ive already got my desired output.